# Is there a way to upload files with Artillery?

Tags: node.js, testing, upload, load, artillery

Is there a good approach to test upload files (form-data) with artillery? The http-file-uploads plugin inly works with Artillery Pro. I tried the solution given in this thread https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/320 writing a beforeRequest Js method, but no success.

```
  const formData = {
    fileOCR: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/files/ocr.png'),
  };

  requestParams.formData = Object.assign({}, requestParams.formData, formData);

  return next();
}
```

My field in form-data for the file is called 'file'

Answer (score 1):

According the [artillery documentation](https://artillery.io/docs/guides/guides/http-reference.html#Multipart-forms-multipart-form-data) to upload a file via `multipart/form-data` you have to create a [custom function](https://artillery.io/docs/guides/guides/http-reference.html#Writing-custom-logic-in-Javascript).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');

function addMultipartFormData(requestParams, context, ee, next) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('files', fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/resources/someFile.pdf'));
    requestParams.body = form;
    return next(); 
}

module.exports = {
  addMultipartFormData,
}
```

Then you can execute this function in the `beforeRequest` hook in your test definition file.

```yaml
- post:
   url: "http://server/file/upload"
   beforeRequest: 'addMultipartFormData'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, this worked for me:

```js
// processor.js
const formData = require('form-data');

function setupMultipartFormData(requestParams, context, ee, next) {
  const form = new formData();
  form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file'));
  requestParams.body = form;
  return next();
}

module.exports = {
  setupMultipartFormData,
}
```

then the yaml.

```yaml
config:
  target: "https://someapi"
  processor: "processor.js"

# ...
scenarios:
 - name: File Upload
    flow:
      - post:
          url: /fileUpload
          beforeRequest: "setupMultipartFormData"
```